# Iterating over rows subtracting by 1 in dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that I would like to iterate from the last non Null value and then subtract 1 from that value for all following rows.

```
z = pd.DataFrame({'l':range(10),'r':[4,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]\
             ,'gh':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,15,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],\
             'gfh':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2]})
df = z.transpose().copy()
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.drop(['index'],axis=1, inplace=True)
df.columns = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']


In [8]: df
Out[8]: 
    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j
0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   2
1 NaN NaN NaN NaN  15 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
3   4 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

I have the above dataframe that I would like to reduce by 1 for everyrow till the last column. For example row 2 the value is 15, so I want 14, 13,12,11,10 to follow. Nothing will follow the 2 in the first row since there are no columns left. Also, the 4 in the last row would be 3,2,1,0,0,0,0 etc.

I reached my desired output by doing the following.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df.iloc[index,df.columns.get_loc(df.iloc[index].last_valid_index())+1:] =\
    [(df.iloc[index,m.columns.get_loc(df.iloc[index].last_valid_index()):][0]-(x+1)).astype(int) \
    for x in range((df.shape[1]-1)-df.columns.get_loc(df.iloc[index].last_valid_index()))] 

df[df < 0] = 0
```

This gives me the desired output

```
In [13]: df
Out[13]: 
    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j
0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   2
1 NaN NaN NaN NaN  15  14  13  12  11  10
2   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
3   4   3   2   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

BUT. In my realworld data I have 50K plus columns and the above code takes WAAAY too long.

Can anyone please suggest how I can make this run faster?
I believe the solution would be to somehow tell the code that once the subtaction equals zero move on to the next row. but Idk how to do that since even if I use  max(0,subtraction formula) the code still waste time subtracting.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how fast it will be, but you could experiment with `ffill`, `fillna`, and `cumsum`.  For example:

```
>>> df
    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j
0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   2
1 NaN NaN NaN NaN  15 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
3   4 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
>>> mask = df.ffill(axis=1).notnull() & df.isnull()
>>> df.where(~mask, df.fillna(-1).cumsum(axis=1).clip_lower(0))
    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i  j
0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  2
1 NaN NaN NaN NaN  15  10   9   8   7  6
2   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8  9
3   4   3   2   1   0   0   0   0   0  0
```

---

This is a little tricky.  First we figure out which cells we need to fill, by forward-filling the rightmost element and seeing whether it's null (there might be a faster way to use last_valid_index tests, but this is the first thing that occurred to me)

```
>>> mask = df.ffill(axis=1).notnull() & df.isnull()
>>> mask
       a      b      c      d      e      f      g      h      i      j
0  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
1  False  False  False  False  False   True   True   True   True   True
2  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
3  False   True   True   True   True   True   True   True   True   True
```

If we fill the empty spots with -1, we can get the values we want by cumulative summing to the right:

```
>>> (df.fillna(-1).cumsum(axis=1))
   a  b  c  d   e   f   g   h   i   j
0 -1 -2 -3 -4  -5  -6  -7  -8  -9  -7
1 -1 -2 -3 -4  11  10   9   8   7   6
2  0  1  3  6  10  15  21  28  36  45
3  4  3  2  1   0  -1  -2  -3  -4  -5
```

Many of those values we don't want, but that's okay, because we're only going to insert the ones we need.  We should clip to 0, though:

```
>>> df.fillna(-1).cumsum(axis=1).clip_lower(0)
   a  b  c  d   e   f   g   h   i   j
0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1  0  0  0  0  11  10   9   8   7   6
2  0  1  3  6  10  15  21  28  36  45
3  4  3  2  1   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

and finally we can use the original ones where mask is False, and the new values where mask is True:

```
>>> df.where(~mask, df.fillna(-1).cumsum(axis=1).clip_lower(0))
    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i  j
0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  2
1 NaN NaN NaN NaN  15  10   9   8   7  6
2   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8  9
3   4   3   2   1   0   0   0   0   0  0
```

(Note: this assumes the rows we need to fill look like the ones in your example.  If they're messier we'd have to do a little more work, but the same techniques will apply.)